# Mount different EFS volumes on AWS Batch at submit_job

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, amazon-efs, aws-batch

I need to mount different EFS volumes on the containers I’m running with AWS Batch (with Fargate), depending on the user of my system.

With boto3 this looks doable with setting the `volumes` and `mountPoints` arguments of the [register_job_definition](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.register_job_definition) method.

Now, what I have are different users that make use of the same Batch Job Definitions, but have separate EFS volumes. So, my problem is: **How can I define which EFS will be mounted on the running containers at job submission?**

On boto3 documentation, [submit_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.submit_job) seems to have many override options, but no explicit args for defining `volumes` and `mountPoints`.

I would really like to avoid creating a separate set Batch Job Definitions per user, since the only thing that changes between Job submissions is the EFS volume.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!